# Remote access to Android local network

Tags: wi-fi, linux, hardware, vpn, accessibility

I have devices connected to Android phone hotspot and phone have internet through LTE. I need access in my phone local network to access all devices web interface.

What solution can you recommend? I think about VPN. I don't want Cloud or paid service.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Servers Ultimate (com.icecoldapps.serversultimate) from Ice Cold Apps to ran VPN Server on your Android device. But it has limitations:

- VNC Server: doesn’t work on most devices.
- ARM based: Caddy, VPN, Port forward, MySQL monitor, Nginx, Traceroute
- Root needed: Port forwarder, VNC, VPN, SMB Native
- Permission SMS: start/stop rules
- Permission coarse location: wifi selector tool

Comment: Most of the features you describe have nothing to do with the question so why do you include them into your answer? Better write a more detailed answer how to use the VPN to achieve what OP asked for. At the moment your answer can be shortened to Use VPN from Servers Ultimate app, but not why and how.